# the way create new repo on github?

Tags: git

[image]searching google, there are ways to create repo on Github.
I'm going to create new repo on github without create the repo on Github, only using git or terminal.
without creating new repo on github, there is no way to create project using only git or terminal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+repository+command+line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create a repository using terminal. With two things [Github Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user) and [Curl](https://www.google.com.pk/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02vcgytoiNC_-9HDrFsRiF9-0mK0A%3A1588844665330&ei=edizXpXZE7LClwTtgrzIBQ&q=curl&oq=curl&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyBQgAEJECMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgIIADICCAAyBQgAEIMBOgQIABBHOgQIIxAnUITrMlj67jJgxPAyaABwAngAgAHRAogBvwaSAQUyLTIuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjV-YTPu6HpAhUy4YUKHW0BD1kQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

If you want to find out whether curl in installed in your PC or not?. you just need to type `curl -help` in your terminal. If no error shows that it is installed already.

You can follow the [Github Api](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user) link and scroll upto the section name `Creates a new repository for the authenticated user`, to add more parameters based on your need,  Here i am just adding two parameter to check whether it is working or not

Parameter 1 (which is required) ----  `name of your repository`

Parameter 2 (for my own test) ---- `making the repository private`

then use this command

```
curl -u "Your_github_username" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"test123","private":"true"}'
```

Be sure to replace `Your_github_username` with you actual github name and I have named  my repository `test123`. You can name it whatever you want.

I am making it private. You dont have to write `private:TRUE`, if you want it to be public.

and then press `Enter`. After that it will ask your github password write it and press enter.

A bunch of code will run in which you will find clone_url which is the link of your repository:

[image]

Comment: hi,
what's `user` in ```https://api.github.com/user/repos ....```?
it's git config `username`?

Comment: i didn't get you what you are asking, can you describe a little bit more?

Comment: `user` is my git config `username`?

Comment: No, dont replace it with anything

Comment: ```$ curl -u "ASSASSIN-GROUP" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name": "angular9app"}'
```
then is this right? i'd like to put it with public. so i removed `private`.

Comment: Yes it is correct. but have you check curl is installed?

Comment: ? how can i install `curl`?

Comment: just tell me the above command runs or not?

Comment: hmm, it's not working for me. there is no response.

Comment: not asking for password in the next command, what error is coming?

Comment: when i press `ctrl+c`, the message comes ```Enter host password for user 'ASSASSIN-GROUP':```
but after run above command, there is no response.

Comment: you dont have to presss ctrl+c, you have to write your github password after pressing enter to the curl command in the next line password is required, you have to write it it will not going to be visible for you when you are writing your password and then press enter buddy!

Comment: hmm, I followed you. unfortunately there is no response.

Comment: you can follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xmFp4_U9-A

Comment: I updated article and added pic. please see it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/).

[`gh repo create [name]`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create)

Comment: when i run `gh repo create[name]`, there was error like this ```bash: gh: command not found```.

Comment: You need to install the CLI tool, it's clearly stated in the link above.

Comment: @StepTNT
I searched installing `gh`, but can't it.

Comment: @ninjadev1030 [The installation instructions](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) and you can [also download a precompiled version of the latest release](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases).

Comment: @Schwern.
Yeah, that works for me. thanks :)